# multiple .htaccess file add Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cors

I have two .htaccess file. One is in the root and the second one is in subfolder. At root I set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin like this:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://mypage.de" 
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.mypage.de"
```

The subfolder is the target of a subdomain and I just want to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to both variants of the subdomain like this:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://sub.mypage.de" 
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.sub.mypage.de"
```

The problem is that I get on my subdomain a 400 bad request error because the 2 definitions from my root are also added to the request when calling the subdomain. Is there a way to reset Access-Control-Allow-Origin or to exclude the subfolder from using the header rules from the root htaccess? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the subfolder, add this before your lines

```
Header unset Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

That should clear the previous headers